# Hierarchy modeling for a CMD simulation of a Bank system

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm searching some help for ideas for a bank system.

This thing is for the University, and teacher put some annoying restrictions such as:

- Make the program in Console, C#.
- Use the Object-Oriented basis (classes, inheritance, encapsulation and polymorphism)
- Don't use something that hasn't been covered in the classroom. The things covered this far are cycles, conditions, arrays (only simple ones), classes, inheritance, encapsulation, classes objects, polymorphism, methods, constructors. Things like lists, properties (Get, Set), foreach loops, work-less functions, and so on are NOT allowed.

With all those eemm, let's leave them 'annoying' restrictions, I need to accomplish this:

A bank system that simulates it's users accounts, with capabilities of retire and deposit money for each user. It MUST be done with the following five classes, with these respective fields:

Class PersonalData:

```
    string userCode;
    string userIdentification;
    string INSSNumber;
    string userName;
    string userLastName;
    int    age;
    string address;
    string phone;
```

Class Account:

```
    string accountNumber;
    string accountType;
    string accountOpenDate;
```

Class Deposit:

```
 string dateDeposit;
 double depositTotal;
 double interest;
```

Class Retire:

```
 string dateRetire;
 double retireTotal;
 double interest;
```

Class FinancieryState

```
 double interest;
 double accountTotal;
```

Inheritance MUST be applied to EVERY class. If a class isn't using inheritance, it will NOT be valid.

Retire and Deposit class has two interest calculation methods, one to know the total interest of all deposits (or retires), and another that will call to the FincieryState class and grow up its interest field. This must be done using polymorphism.

Okay, basically those are all the requirements, may be I'm missing a couple ones, as fast as I remember them I'll write them.

What I've done so far:

Make to PersonalData the 'Super Parent' class.
Account inherits from PersonalData.
FinancieryState inherits from Account.
Deposit inherits from FinancieryState.
Retire inheits from FinancieryState.

Fill-up to every class with their respective methods and constructors to fill-up fields and update/calculate the numeric ones.

A Main entry for menus such as deposit for a specific client, view state of a client's account, etc.

Now, I must store all the data of a new user in a single object of whatever type.

Finally, the question:

What can I do to have in a single object to the user, and be able to view its deposit and retire information, apply the polymorphism part to these two classes, and be able to calculate the accountTotal field of the FinancieryState class with the help of the information given by the deposit and retire classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. A casting was enough.

I've changed the inheritance squence to be this:

Make to PersonalData the 'Super Parent' class. Account inherits from PersonalData. FinancieryState inherits from Account. Deposit inherits from FinancieryState. Retire inheits from Deposit.

Then, the data is stored in a `Retire` object, to get retire info it's enough to do a `myObject.GetRetireTotal()`.

If its for the deposit info it would change to `((Deposit)myObject).GetDepositTotal()`.

And so on...